# Form's submit and validate functions not being called

Tags: 7, forms

I can't submit any form. If I press *Submit* button on any form, the form page gets reloaded and nothing happens and no message is shown.

In the submit and validate functions of a form, I added an `exit()` command and found that they are not being called at all.

I cleared the cache and problem still exists.
Any suggestion?

Comment: can you please add the code ?

Comment: This happens for all forms.

Comment: @user16948 did you modify any core files? or are you implementing the functions in your custom module (using `hook_form_alter`)? posting the code would help to find the actual cause as mohit_rocks said.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `post_max_size` in *.htaccess* file. I was using `MB` instead of `M` after the value.